# LINQ получить проблемный элемент

Tags: .net, linq

Можно ли в LINQ получить элемент на котором свалилось выполнение запроса?

Ну скажем, я запускаю арифметическую операцию и не с того не с сего происходит деление на 0.

Могу я как-то посмотреть на него в режиме отладки?

Comment: `try - catch - exception`?

Comment: Как вариант, можете создать свой метод расширение.

Comment: Подробнее можете проблему описать? Обычно при исключении можно навести курсор на переменную и посмотреть увидеть ее значение

Comment: @АндрейNOP, если не ошибаюсь, то это не работает в LINQ и он тупо вываливает ошибку. Т.е нельзя получить конкретно элемент, где он споткнулся. Например примердля иллюстрации list.Where(x=>5/x). Если тут произойдет деление на 0, то я не смогу получить сам X, где эта операция произошла.

Comment: Да вроде нормально работает: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lRhV.png

Comment: Не понимаю, почему мой ответ не подходит в качестве решения. Я должен был написать код к неизвестно чему?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, а всегда так было? Точно помню, что, вроде, он когда-то выплевывал ошибку не давая посмотреть на элемент имеющий причину ошибки.

Comment: Да вроде всегда, последние пару лет — точно, что было раньше я не знаю :)